# coffeescript: suppress "ReferenceError"

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript

Currently working through [this](http://adamjspooner.github.io/coffeescript-meet-backbonejs/) tutorial on using Backbone.js with coffeescript.

Leveraging the following `index.html` file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CoffeeScript, Meet Backbone.js: Part N</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.6/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>CoffeeScript, Meet Backbone.js: Part 1</h1>
  </header>
</body>


</html>
```

which loads an `index.js` file after loading Backbone, jQuery, etc from a cdn. Hoping to work within a `script.coffee` file that I'd like to have automatically compile into the `script.js` file loaded by `index.html` above by running something like `coffee script.coffee -c -w.`

Trouble is, I'm getting `ReferenceError`s  when I try to run the above command on the following `script.coffee` file:

```
jQuery ->

  class ListView extends Backbone.View

    el: $ 'body'

    initialize: ->

      _.bindAll @
      @render()

    render: ->
      $(@el).append '<ul><li>Hello, Backbone!</li></ul>'

  list_view = new ListView
```

For instance:

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
...
```

because, clearly, jQuery is being loaded in the `index.html` file.

Is there a way to suppress the error reporting from the coffeescript compiler so that it just converts the code without the error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The options must go *before* the file, e.g.:

```
coffee -cw script.coffee
```

Otherwise, it will try to run `script.coffee` right then and there as a Node.js script, passing it the options `-c` and `-w`. That's not what you want; if you want the CoffeeScript compiler to get the options, it's got to be before the file name.